# How to pass the name of the mysql database as a parameter in DatabaseInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to create a multi-tenancy archictecture in asp.net CORE. However I am unable to change the tenant name after the start.cs file is executed. I dont know How to do this I have tried httpContext without success any help would be verry appriciated.

Here is the relevant code for my start.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            services.AddScoped<TenantInfo>();
            services.UseSchemaPerTenant(Configuration);

            TenantInfo tenantInfo = new TenantInfo();
            tenantInfo.Name = "erp_colombia";

            services.AddTransient<DatabaseMigrator>();

            services.AddDbContext<erp_colombiaDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(
                     Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).AddInterceptors(new DatabaseInterceptor(tenantInfo)));

            services.AddIdentityCore<Employee>(options =>
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
            ).AddRoles<Entities.Type>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<erp_colombiaDbContext>();
}
```

Then I have this controller that I want To call in order to change the name

```
[HttpGet("seed")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Seed(string tenantNewName)
{
    if (_hostingEnv.IsDevelopment())
    {
        _output = new StringBuilder("---DATABASE SEED---\n");


        TenantInfo tenantInfo = new TenantInfo();
        tenantInfo.Name = tenantNewName;

        _migrator.Execute();

        _output.AppendLine("Ensured database is created and applied all pending migrations");


        _output.AppendLine("Done!");

        return Ok(_output.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        _output.AppendLine($"Database can ONLY be generated in DEV MODE!!!!");
        return Ok(_output.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my DatabaseInterceptor

```
public class DatabaseInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        private readonly TenantInfo tenantInfo;
        
    
        public DatabaseInterceptor(TenantInfo tenantInfo)
        {
            this.tenantInfo = tenantInfo;
        }
    
        public override Task<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command,
            CommandEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
    
            if (tenantInfo.Name == null)
            {
                tenantInfo.Name = "erp_colombia";
            }
            command.CommandText = $"USE {tenantInfo.Name}; {command.CommandText}";
    
            return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `USE` is a SQL Server command. You can't use it with MySQL. In any case, it's *far* safer to connect to the correct database directly. The [EF Core Multitenancy document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#multiple-databases-and-connection-strings) shows injecting a Tenant ID service into the DbContext and asking that service for the correct connection string. That's far safer than starting in one database and trying to switch to another, risking staying in the wrong database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that mysql and sql are diffrent when I say database in mysql what In mean is I want to change the schema

Comment: In MySQL schema and database are the same thing. You can use a different connection string to connect to the correct database from the start

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can I change the connection string in public async Task<IActionResult> Seed?